# Losing Controller Scope in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Well . . . a cursory look at my code should save me from having to explain that I'm brand new to Angular, I'm sure.

I'm building an app that allows search text from a user, queries a database when the value of the text input changes, then produces a list of matches. The back end is simple and is working. On the front, I've got the search field and the results container:

```
<div id="search" ng-controller="FormController">
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Start typing . . ." ng-keypress="search()" ng-model="searchField" id="search-field">

    <div id="results" class="alert alert-success">
        <a href="#" ng-href="#" ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="add(item)">
            <p class="lead text-left">
                <span>{{item.DisplayName}} -</span>
                <span> {{item.Description}} -</span>
                <span> {{item.Count}} ct. -</span>
                <span> ${{item.Price}}</span>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check pull-right"></span>
            </p>
        </a>
        <h4>{{noResults}}</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

**The two methods being called in my controller:**

```
$scope.search = function()
{
    $scope.$watch('searchField', function (newValue)
    {
        if (newValue)
        {
            $http.post('/search', 
            {
                val: newValue
            })
            .success(function (response)
            {
                if (response.length > 0)
                {
                    $scope.items = response;
                    $scope.noResults = '';

                }
                else 
                {
                    $scope.noResults = 'No Matches Found';
                    $scope.items = '';
                }
            })
            .error(function (response)
            {
                console.log('Oooops, error: ' + response);
            });
        }
    });
};

$scope.add = function(item)
{
    console.log('added');
};
```

`$scope.search()`, while probably a little messy, is working. But the `add()` method is not called on click. I'm guessing I'm simply not in the scope of the controller at that point, but after a LOT of searching around, I turn to you, stumped. I'm at the "banging-your-head-against-the-keyboard-and-hoping-for-it-to-magically-work" stage.

Is this an inheritance issue?

** Update **
Here is the entire controller (with the `$watch` removed as suggested in the comments):

```
var app = angular.module('AppModule', ['toastr']);

app.controller('FormController', ['$scope', '$http', 'toastr', function($scope, $http, toastr)
{

    $scope.search = function()
    {
        var searchText = $scope.searchField;

        $http.post('/search', 
        {
            val: $scope.searchField
        })
        .success(function (response)
        {
            if (response.length > 0)
            {
                $scope.items = response;
                $scope.noResults = '';

            }
            else 
            {
                $scope.noResults = 'No Matches Found';
                $scope.items = '';
            }
        })
        .error(function (response)
        {
            console.log('Oooops, error: ' + response);
        });
    };

    $scope.add = function(item)
    {
        console.log('added');
    };

}]);
```

**Update 2**

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/pXqv6m9lBatwthc0RknX?p=preview) is a plunker showing that everything is working up til the `add()` method (I may have renamed that method in this version). Of course, in place of my `$http` post, I've hard-coded a fake of the response that comes back from the server.

Comment: Can you make a plunker demonstrating your problem. From my testing, looks like your code works. You probably want to take that watch out of the search function and just call $http directly.

Comment: Well, I tried to make a version of the above without the search functionality and the backend, and, well, the bare-bones version [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/RpDiBSqUM10qOMrHtiEx?p=preview) works, so I guess that's not very helpful.

Comment: RE:, the `$watch` thing . . . not sure how I would send the value of the search field to the back end without it. Certainly open to suggestions. There's definitely some recursion ugliness there.

Comment: You are watching `searchField` so you have the value as `$scope.searchField`. As for the other problem, looks like you need to provide more code. Since you can't get a demo to show the problem its really hard to help debug.

Comment: Okay, that's great. Much nicer to look at. Still no access to `add()`, however.

Comment: can you post your complete controller code?

Comment: you should try using "FormController as form" then add form before each one of your scope variables on the html, like "form.items", "form.add()" etc

Comment: is `response.length > 0` returning `undefined`? (i dont think you can get length of an object this way, you can probably use an object's `key` for that though) -- probably doesn't affect the add() regardless.

Comment: Try removing the href and ng-href.  I can't remember which takes priority, but one may be preventing the execution of the other.

Comment: @FelipeSkinner: I'll have to look into that "form as" thing. I don't know anything about it. @Shehryar: `response` comes back as an empty array if there isn't any data, so `response.length` should be 0 in that case, right?

Comment: that depends, do you mean you get this as an empty array: `[{  }]` this would still be an object, right?

Comment: Well . . . an array IS an object, but the response is literally `[]` if there is no data.

Comment: okay let's check what happens if you change to: ng-click=add() without a param and remove it from add() function to. if this works then we'll know if add() was receiving a real value or undefined, right? (the only reason being that your bare-bones fiddle works just fine with hard coded data)

Comment: There isn't anything wrong with the code you have provided that I can see.  It works.  

Is there any other code on the html page (like maybe an unclosed tag??) or something?  Your $scope is fine.  You aren't getting any errors?

Comment: you are actually short circuiting your function call.  you should remove both `href="#"` and `ng-href="#"`, because they will cause `ng-click` to never fire.

Comment: @Claies don't believe that is the case.  The code is working for me fine.  I'm quite sure a route change (which it isn't even doing) doesn't tamper with ng-click.

Comment: another possibility is that there is another variable on `$scope` called `add` which is overwriting the function.  There are some good articles about "always using a dot in the scope"....

Comment: I really appreciate all the suggestions, but I've tried all of that (with the exception of `FormController as form`, which I'll look into tomorrow. I've been trying to get a use-case up on plunker, but I'm having issues there. I'll come back to this tomorrow, with a clearer head. Thanks again.

Comment: Added a plunker link to my post. Finally got a decent replication of my issue up there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS issue. Comment out line, *ugh*, 8382 of your CSS (setting #results display to none). It'll work then. How you eventually resolve this in your CSS is a different issue.

Comment: Huh. Can't listen for an event on an element that isn't visible? Geez. And I'm with you on the "ugh". Bower and Grunt make it too easy to just ignore the fact that you have a few thousand lines of CSS you're not using since you never have to look at it. This is purely a dev project, not a design project. Much obliged for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Went through your plunker and i must say that the issue found is kinda silly.

At first, i put the code for removing the class `has-value` from resultsContainer in a timeout. That made the call for addItem working.

```
  setTimeout(function() {
      resultsContainer.removeClass('has-value');
  }, 1000);
```

This may act as a solution, but setTimeout ?? Not happening.

Digging a little deep revealed that you are using display:none for #results. So i removed the display css and used opacity instead.

```
    #results {
      position: absolute;
      /*display: none; */
       opacity : 0; 
      top: 100%;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
    }
    #results.has-value {
      display: block;
       opacity : 1;
    }
```

This got it working without the timeout. **Now i have myself faced issues where display:none screws the functionalities. So you either tweak your css or use a timeout instead. **

**Also, consider moving that code in a directive.**

Updated plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/pXqv6m9lBatwthc0RknX?p=preview)

Comment: Ha, Andy beat you by a hair. `display:none` hasn't caused me any trouble until now. That strikes me as maybe classifiable as an Angular bug. And, oh yes, directives are on my list. I'm just trying to get the basics down first.

Comment: Yeah. and trust me, in majority of the cases when the bindings don't work, always try using timeout. It helps out :D

Comment: I'm gonna really try and remember that. Somehow, I suspect next time I'm still gonna bang my head against the wall for a few hours before I remember this conversation :)